# How to disable window maximizing when dragging to top panel

Tags: unity, compiz, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn off Compiz's “drag to maximize” behaviour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72452/how-to-turn-off-compizs-drag-to-maximize-behaviour)

Unity mimics the behavior of Windows 7's Aero Snap. That is, when dragging a window and hitting the top panel with the mouse, the window gets maximized. Is there a way to prevent this, at least for me, annoying behavior?