# How to turn off Compiz's "drag to maximize" behaviour? 

Tags: compiz

Just starting to use Unity with 11.10, and obviously there are a lot of changes to get used to. One of the most annoying is the habit it has of trying to maximize a window when I drag it up against the top bar to position it.

How do I disable this behaviour? I assume there's a toggle in CCSM somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: this works for 11.04 classic desktop as well and has nothing to do with unity.

Comment: Great, I have been looking for how to disable this annoyance for so long, just didn't know what it was called! Even posted the same question which went unresolved.

Comment: These solutions don't work for me. Windows still automatically expand when they're pulled close to the top edge. It's quite annoying. I wonder why someone thought it would be a good idea. kentfx

Comment: These don't work for me either. I am using ubnutu 17.10. Does anyone have any idea how to toggle this feature?

Comment: I switched to cinnamon. It solved.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Recommended**

If you simply want to turn off this feature then run the following in a terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/grid/screen0/options/top_edge_action --type int 0
```

Alternatively - with a GUI, use `gconf-editor`:

[image: Compiz configuration options]

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I like the grid keypad actions, so just setting the thresholds to 0 gives me the behaviour I want.

Comment: While it's nice to have a non-compiz answer, I personally prefer BinaryLife's answer -- the GUI version. It exposes more related settings and you're not poking at numeric values.

Answer (score 37):

You can disable it from `ccsm` :  [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

Go to Windows management-->  Grid --> Edges --> Re-size Actions

Top Edge: change it to none.

[image]

Comment: Anytime,Glad to help!

Comment: Very good. I switched off all edges to get rid of that when I pull the window to another desktop.

Comment: Still valid for 16.10 and 17.04. Works like a charm! Dare I say it? Yes. I will Thank you! This was driving me crazy.

Comment: how is that in KDE?

Comment: in KDE Alt+Space type Edges to find 'System Settings' for 'Screen Edges'

Answer (score 0):

Update for Ubuntu Mate 21.10 in case anyone finds via search. The layout of CCSM 1.0.9.14.1 has completely changed.  To change the proper setting, select Window Management on the left, then click the Grid icon. It will switch to a detailed settings page, with the Bindings tab selected. Switch to the Corners/Edges tab.  Finally, on the Top Edge line, change the drop down to None.

Hope this helps someone.