# is there a way to turn off the drag to maximize thing?

Tags: 11.04, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn off Compiz's “drag to maximize” behaviour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72452/how-to-turn-off-compizs-drag-to-maximize-behaviour)

when you move a window in 11.04 classic desktop and the mouse goes over the top of the window it gets auto maximized. Is there a way to disable this?

[How to turn off Compiz's "drag to maximize" behaviour?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72452/10698)

This question is about the same thing, but I don't use Unity or 11.10 that's why that answer wont work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be the same since it's a compiz plugin that is responsible for that.