# Force disable snapping windows

Tags: 11.10, compiz, window-manager, cairo-dock

How can I reliably disable snapping windows?  When I drag a window around by its titlebar and near the upper edge, it tints and wants to maximize if I let go of the mouse then (trying to park my app there, not cover the whole workspace!)

Until Unity becomes more productive for my work style I switched to cairo-dock with effects for now (which also is not without issues).

As the logged in user I have run `ccsm` the Compiz manager and disabled **Snapping Windows** altogether, and verified many times.  Doesn't seem to care.  Haven't filed a bug rep yet as maybe there's some other setting I don't know about.  Nothing else results in the CompizConfig search when I try *snap* or *snapping*.  Any other ideas?

Ubuntu Desktop 11.10 32bit, **hwinfo**:

```
 28: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)
  [Created at pci.318]
  UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/pci_1002_7145
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "ATI Radeon Mobility X1400"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x7145 "Radeon Mobility X1400"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1025 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0094 
  Driver: "radeon"
  Driver Modules: "drm"
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xd7ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x2000-0x2fff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xc8100000-0xc810ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xc8120000-0xc813ffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 46 (306 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00007145sv00001025sd00000094bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: radeon is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe radeon"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #13 (PCI bridge)
```

Comment: Could it possibly get reactivated by some event eg. sliding to another workspace?  Having trouble finding a cause that's consequential.  Snapping just seems to come back at some point and I can't figure out why.

Comment: disabling "Place Windows" under ccsm's "Window Management" also made it stop snapping to top border.  However that plugin seems to be more another victim than cause to whatever underlying problem, and needed to re-enable anyway it to avoid ill effects without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer turned out to be wrong (not always off).

Finally found the answer! https://askubuntu.com/a/72480/38636

Seems it's also know as “drag to maximize” behaviour in Compiz and disabled in CCSM Grid plugin, Edges tab, Top Edge :: set to None.

Answer (score 2):

Disabled "Scale" under ccsm's "Window Management" .... and snapping to maximize suddenly stopped, finally!  A lot of other things changed too, namely many updates since last month.

It would go such a long way if this plugin like so much else had a nearby description of what it actually does and when...not just "Scale Windows" on ccsm's left column and *nothing else mentioned*.

Comment: Excellent & well done. If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling wobbly windows in ccsm.  I know that you cannot have snapping windows working when wobbly is activated.  This may work, for it is what i have selected in my own compiz

Comment: Thanks, I tried that suggestion. Their effects both seems to coexist without interference though, and selecting incurred new latency before getting ready to be moved, so I switched Wobbly back off. Maybe Snapping goes by another name in some other daemon/setting?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you havve ccsm and you have the Grid feature enabled.

1. Go to CompizConfig Settings Manager.
2. Click Window Management.
3. Go to Resize Actions tab.
4. Set all values in Grid Snapback Thresholds to 0.

This will disable your windows from snapping. If you want the feature back, just reset all the values to their defaults. :-)

[Here's a screenshot of the Grid settings menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwqE7.png)