# How to disable windows snapping to the side?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have this particular problem into my screen:
[image]

How can I make this orange frame on my screen disappear? It happens after I move windows to the side. The problem is that is sticks.

My VGA driver is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
```

I have installed the proprietary `nvidia-340` driver. I'm using 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Isn't that the *"click-and-hold-and-drag"* selection frame? Like for selecting multiple icons on the desktop?

Comment: Yes it happens when I click hold and drag a window torwads on the side and in the end I do not want to move to the side at all.

Comment: That question has a few answes, but in particular pay attention to this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/46780/518562