# Turn off Unity feature?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable window maximizing when dragging to top panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46779/how-to-disable-window-maximizing-when-dragging-to-top-panel)

Is there a way to turn off the " bug " in Unity where the windows go full screen when you touch them to the edge of the screen. This bad idea really bugs me.

Answer (score 2):

It's a setting in compiz.

If you load up ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) and look at the Grid plugin in the Windows management section.  To disable it completely, you can untick the "Grid" plugin in ccsm and it will no longer snap like in Windows.

The main part to look at is the Edges tab in the ccsm dialog. You can disable each edge action by changing the option to "None"

Comment: This worked for me on 13.10 whereas changing settings with gconf-editor had no effect.